# Symfony 3 probleme with authentication

Tags: authentication, symfony

Hi guys i have a probleme with the guard authentication I use symfony 3.1 in my project the guard authentication work fine in my local machine but when i deploy to the server if the authentication succeed i am redirecting to the home page but i loose the authentication and become anonymous again.
Event when i want to register a new user in the deployement it doesnt work the error is bad csrf.
seems like in the deployement the navigator dont send cookies or dont accept them.
I am really confus cause all this work fine in my local server
Really need help.
Thx

security.yml :

```
security:
    encoders:
        UserBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt
    providers:
        database_users:
            entity: {class: UserBundle:User, property: mail}
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - form_login_authenticator
```

confing.yml :

```
    imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@VendeurBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
    - { resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: fr

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
        cookie_lifetime: 1000

    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form_themes:
        - 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            timestampable: true

white_october_pagerfanta:
    exceptions_strategy:
        out_of_range_page:        ~
        not_valid_current_page:   ~
```

Controller :

```
    /**
 * @Route("/connexion", name="security_login")
 */
public function loginAction()
{
    if ($this->isAuthenticated()) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    }
    $helper = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
    return $this->render(':connexion:login.html.twig', array(
        // last username entered by the user (if any)
        'last_username' => $helper->getLastUsername(),
        // last authentication error (if any)
        'error' => $helper->getLastAuthenticationError(),
    ));
}

/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
 * @Security("is_authenticated()")
 */
public function logoutAction()
{
    $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);
    return $this->redirectToRoute("homepage");
}

/**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="security_login_check")
 */
public function loginCheckAction()
{
    // will never be executed
}
```

Update : I found the probleme the server destroy the session for every request but i dont know how to solve it.

Comment: Please show some code!!!!

Comment: Thx but Code of what section config.yml security.yml or controlller.I think also that the server delete the session since i get the csrf in the form registration.

Comment: Information on routes and security settings are needed, so you can show those details.

Comment: @Alvin i update the question and i recall that this work fine on my local server so i dont think its a probleme of code

Comment: I found the probleme the server destroy the session for every request but i dont know how to solve it.

Comment: I don't think I'm able to help, because I haven't used guard. Things look ok, but maybe someone else can help. Have you tried using the DEV URL, by appending `app_dev.php` to any of your URLs, and then checking the `var/logs/dev.log` log file to see what it shows? This might help.

Comment: Yes there is no error and i dont even think irs guard error the session is just deleted